# input text width not 100% responsive on all devices

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I've fonud this StackOverFlow questions and it seemed to make sense for my situation:
[Input text box and width 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991659/input-text-box-and-width-100)

I'm simply trying to make an input type="text" form (where a user types in information) 100% wide on all devices/dimensions (240, 320, 480, 768, 1024).

My HTML is:

```
<div align="left">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td>input type="text" name="first_name" style="width: 100%;" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
```

My CSS:

```
input { width: 100%; }
```

I can't seem to get the input text area 100% wide??? On an iphone (320) its too wide and makes you scroll left/right. Any suggestions? Thank You!

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to set the width of the table first, and also the first , like this:

```html
<div>
  <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr style="width:100%;">
      <td style="width:8em;">First Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="first_name" style="width:100%;" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! That worked for IE/Chrome. But on an iphone (320) its still too wide and makes you scroll left/right. Any suggestions there? Also- is it ok to use style="width:100%;" in a table for responsive "mobile friendly" reasons? I'm told we shouldn't speciy width in tables anymore? Thanks!

Comment: sorry i dont know if i tagged you